# Independent Variables and Array performance

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, variables, unity-game-engine

I would like to know what is more optimal, A number N of private integer variables, or a single array containing N integer values.

Comment: I would be surprised if you can measure the difference in anything other than a completely artificial test.

Comment: Your question is unclear and makes not much sense, please reformulate it.

Comment: I agree with Richard: If you can write n private integers, then it's probably not enough to make any difference then an array of lenght n. I suspect you will only be able to start measuring a difference in performance if n is at least 5-6 digits long.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it as to do so would be premature optimization. The compiler is going to take care of those details for you, so you can concentrate on the business logic. If performance does turn out to be an issue later, it will be measurable and you'll be able to isolate and deal with it then.

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that you shouldn't obsess too much in advance about the micro-efficiencies of things that are _private_. Even if you care about efficiency, the fact that these things are private means you can grab a profiler and change them to your heart's content without rewriting your entire codebase. If there's any part of efficiency worth thinking about in advance above all else, it's how your interfaces work in the _public_ parts that the rest of your codebase is going to be using. There you can't necessarily change your mind so easily.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an array, that is a plus indirection. The array will be allocated at a separate part of the memory, so when you first access it, your code first obtains its address, then it is able to read out its content. It also needs some indexing, but that is done extremly fast by the CPU. However, .NET is a safe environment and it will do a check whether you use a valid array index. It adds additional time. 
When you use separate variables, these will be encompassed by your object instance and no indirection is needed. Also, no index bound check is needed.
Moreover, you cannot name nicely the Nth element of an array, but you can give good names for individual variables. So your code will be readable.
As others mentioned, you shouldn't do this kind of optimalizations, the compiler/jitter take care of it. The compiler knows several common use cases and has optimialization strategy for that. If you start doing tricky things, the compiler will not recognize your intention and cannot make the optimalization for you.

Comment: Thank you, i will keep my code readable then.